# Identify that a string could be a datetime object

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, python-2.7, datetime

If I knew the format in which a string represents date-time information, then I can easily use `datetime.datetime.strptime(s, fmt)`. However, without knowing the format of the string beforehand, would it be possible to determine whether a given string contains something that could be parsed as a datetime object with the right format string?

Obviously, generating every possible format string to do an exhaustive search is not a feasible idea. I also don't really want to write one function with many format strings hardcoded into it.
Does anyone have any thoughts on how this can be accomplished (perhaps some sort of regex?)?

Comment: Date and time parsing is a complex problem, due to the many formats and orders used. If you have tons of different formats you have tons of problems. And you can not even be use if 01-02-2015 is in January or February. No automated system can handle this. So, you will have to solve the date format problem at the source and make use you get parsable consistent data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [fuzzyparsers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzyparsers):

Sample inputs:

```
jan 12, 2003
jan 5
2004-3-5
+34 -- 34 days in the future (relative to todays date)
-4 -- 4 days in the past (relative to todays date)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> from fuzzyparsers import parse_date
>>> parse_date('jun 17 2010') # my youngest son's birthday
datetime.date(2010, 6, 17)
```

Install with:

```
$ pip install fuzzyparsers
```

Comment: Happy belated 5th birthday, son of James!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `parser` from [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

**Example usage:**

```
from dateutil import parser
dt = parser.parse("Aug 28 1999 12:00AM")
```

Comment: Note: The `fuzzyparsers` answer by James Mills can handle some imputs that this cannot, such as `+34` or `-4` and thus might be more useful in a more controllable system (where you can install fuzzyparsers), however, if you are running on ideone, for example, then dateutil is there, but fuzzyparsers is not.